Power Query: how to sum up values in each column separately and get a new table with two columns: column_name, column_sum
help me please with such a task, please: i have a table



patient id
loc1
loc2
loc3
....
locN




3545
0
0
1

0


3546
0
0
0
....



3547
1
0





3548
0
1        ......





....








How can i sum up all numbers in each column and get the next table:
|  loc  |  sum  |
|  loc1 |  235  |
|  loc2 |  511  |
.....
|  locN |  1026 |
Thanks in advance for any idea!
I know how to sum up all values of each selected column, but i have about 20 columns, so i want to do this automatically for all ones.

you can select the first column and unpivot other columns in PQ


then do the group by



Ryan, it works, thank you very much! I'm new in Power BI and I'm just learning different tools like column pivot/unpivot
